# How to join dim_date table for appears first_of_month_date

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, which I should join and for empty rows must add upper value. The problem is after join with dim_date table the dates for missed dates in general query doesn't appear.
For instance, for exactly id I got the rows, but if it in flow I can't. first table that I have, the second that I want to have.
[image]
[image]
DB - Redshift

```
select first_day_of_month, last_value(c_loan_agreement_id) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY first_day_of_month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)  c_loan_agreement_id from business_core.dim_date dd
left join business_core.fact_receivable_repayment frr  on date_trunc('month',frr.repayment_date) =dd.first_day_of_month 
where dd.first_day_of_month <= '2023-12-01' and dd.first_day_of_month>= '2022-12-01' 
group by  c_loan_agreement_id, first_day_of_month, frr.repayment_date;
```

Comment: @Justin Swanhart doesn't help! And I need left join caz all from dim_date table should be if i choose right join, then alll from tbl2 will be.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Make it easy to help you! (The current wall of SQL and tiny image text make most people turn back.)

Comment: @jarlh I added minimal reproducible example

Comment: Please don't use images - add all information as editable text (so someone can copy it if they want to try out a solution). Please update your question to show the DDL for the tables involved, enough sample data for those tables to illustrate the various use cases and the result you want to see based on that sample data

Comment: Do not use this in your LEFT JOIN: `and  dd.first_day_of_month <= '2023-12-01' and dd.first_day_of_month>= '2022-12-01'`.  The records that are not in that months will be filter by the WHERE-clause.

Comment: @NickW hey, I used picture only for table now. And saved more simple variant of the qeury.